# Estimation covariance function?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, estimation

Let $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be an independent sample associated to a statistical model $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_{\theta}).$

If we suppose that the distrubtion of each $X_i$ under $\mathbb{P}_{\theta}$ has a density function $f(\cdot,\theta)$ then we can estimative the likelihood function.

So we can perform estimation for univariate gaussian, multivariate gaussian.

**Now** I am interested about gaussian processes.

Suppose that we would like to estimate a covariance function $K(s,t)$ which can have any licit form.

> My question is:
>
> How can I estimate a covariance function ? What are the methods that already exist?

If the estimation is only about finite dimensional law therefor I don't understand what is the difference between estimation of multivariate Gaussian and estimation of gaussian process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a GP model, and you have a parametric form for the covariance operator, then you can just use maximum likelihood or any other estimation approach.

However, you need to have observations associated with the covariates(observations $Y_1,...,Y_n$ associated with covariates $X_1,...,X_n$), or vice versa: if $X_1,...,X_n$ are the observations, some set of covariates $t_1,...,t_n$. Moving forward we'll use $X_i$ to denote a covariate and $Y_i$ to denote it's associated observation.

Suppose that $Y \sim \textrm{GP}(0,K_\theta(s,t))$, where $\exp(\frac{1}{2\theta}||s-t||^2)$, then you have that the marginal distributions of $Y_1,...,Y_n$ is jointly normal with distribution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{N}(0, K_\theta(X,X))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $K(X,X) = [\exp(\frac{1}{2\theta}||x_i - x_j||^2)]_{ij}$. You can optimize this over $\theta$ to get the MLE. The marginal Gaussianity gives you some asymptotic properties on the estimator for $\hat{\theta}$, but I'm not sure off the top off my head if it's the same stuff as in standard parametric settings.

You could also use some sort of [empirical auto-covariance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765442/what-does-the-empirical-autocovariance-function-represent) to get a nonparametric estimator of the auto-covariance operator. I don't know much about this, but I think various types exist, and you can sort of try and model different types of auto-covariances (like stationarity, whether it's isotropic or not, etc.) using different formulations. I would imagine that studying properties of these estimators is fairly technical. I couldn't find many references from a brief search.

Comment: thanks this exactly what I am trying to understand. If I have a parametric form how does I write the likelihood ? Ins't just the likelihood for multivariate gaussian ?

Comment: It's the likelihood of a multivariate Gaussian, but with the parameter to be optimized embedded in the covariance of the Gaussian distribution. That is, if $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, then for a sample of size $n$ $K_\theta(X,X)$ as a function of $\theta$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^p\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. This covariance is going to be inside the function $f(K_\theta(X,X)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi|\Sigma|}}\exp\{\sum_{i=1}^nY^T_i K_\theta(X,X) Y_i\}$; giving you that you need to optimize $f(\theta): \mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as a function of $\theta$.

Comment: Ok very nice explanation. Do you know where I can found exemple of maximum likelihood estimation for parametric covariance operator ?Everything I found is pretty succinct.